# Load ads of webpage on purpose in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I'm creating a python application which webscrapes pages and downloads media from a certain website. This has a few effects:

1. Ad revenue goes down because people use my application instead of going to the website.
2. Bandwidth to the website increases because my application makes it easier to download from the website.
3. There will be users that aren't using the website, but indirectly will via my application, increasing the user count of the website.

It all leads to more usage of the website and less ad revenue. That's not nice to the website owner so I want to compensate.

---

***Every time I fetch a page from the website, I want to also load the ads on the page, so the owner owns money from my fetches via ads.***

My thoughts:

- Fetch the page using `selenium` and wait 2 seconds. The ads will load (I think?) and that's enough to "count".
- Fetch the page using `selenium`, find all the ad URLs and fetch them all (will this increase revenue even more because clicking is worth more than viewing?)

What will work? What do I need to do for the owner to earn money from my fetches?